# Unable to install ddtrace using poetry on M1 Max

Tags: python, datadog, python-poetry

I have a new M1 Max machine (Monterey) and when I run poetry install I get the error `Installing ddtrace (1.4.5): Failed`.

There's a long stack trace you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/NRKirby/7ae65d4d92ce828455d03726a7c03367)

the first error appears to be

`ddtrace/internal/pack_template.h:561:5: error: implicit declaration of function '_PyFloat_Pack8' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration] _PyFloat_Pack8(d, &buf[1], 0);`

I am unsure how to debug this issue - can anyone help?

Comment: do you have to use `v1.4.5` precisely? I recently encountered a poetry install error with ddtrace. I just relaxed the requirements to a range instead. Try out another package version